# Is there a "paired t test" like test that considers the sign of the difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I'm looking to see if a new material has an impact on sample results.
To analyze the impact I am running the samples using both materials.
Using the paired t-test there is one outlier that is keeping the test from failing.
All samples except the one outlier decrease in value with the new material.
The experiment also naturally has high variation.

Correct me if I'm wrong,
But it seems as though standard deviation does not consider the sign of the difference and so the test does not consider the probability of all differences having the same sign.

Is there a test that can take this into consideration?

Comment: Wilcoxon test, or sign test.

Comment: That'll do. Cheers